# Musical People Chain

Tags: visual, rebus, music

1. [image]

---

2. [image]

---

3. [image]

---

4. [image]

---

5. [image]

---

**Question**: Can you tell who connects image 1 to image 2, who connects image 2 to image 3, who connects image 3 to image 4 and who connects image 4 to image 5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### *aye, lets have it then*

OK so

1. is

   > Swing Out Sister, one member of which was Andy Connell, who was in
2. is

   > A Certain Ratio, who was on the Factory Records label under the management of Tony Wilson, who also managed
3. is

   > Joy Division, consisting in part of Bernard Sumner who was in
4. is

   > Bad Lieutenant (or it's a lieutenant in a *New Order*, no less), which at one point included Alex James of
5. is

   > Blur

Comment: The first image could refer to "Swing out sister".

Comment: @Gamow Thank you - I always forget that nurses are sometimes called "sisters"

Comment: Very close. I was looking for a person, rather than a label, for the link between 2 and 3.

Comment: @GordonK OK, how's that?

Comment: That'll do nicely!